# SQLite PRAGMA table_info(table) not returning column names (using Data.SQLite in C#)

Tags: c#, sqlite

I use the following example code and want to get the column names of a sqlite3 database in some way:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SQLite;
namespace Program
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program stuff = new Program();
        stuff.DoStuff();
        Console.Read();
    }
    private void DoStuff()
    {
        SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("Database.sqlite");
        SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Database.sqlite;Version=3;");
        con.Open();
        string sql = "create table 'member' ('account_id' text not null unique, 'account_name' text not null);";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, con);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sql = "insert into member ('account_id', 'account_name') values ('0', '1');";
        command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, con);
        sql = "PRAGMA table_info('member');";
        command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, con);
        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetName(0));
        }
        con.Close();
    }

}
}
```

I also tried

```
for(int i=0;i<reader.FieldCount;i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine(reader.GetName(i));
}

var columns = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).Select(reader.GetName).ToList();
```

the only result I get is the following output:
"cid name type notnull dflt_value pk"
I dont get the actual column names though..
I do need the column names because I'm writing new columns to the database depending on the result of an API from another server where I dont have access to. When printing the data, I oc want to make sure the correct column names are displayed.

Comment: I am using System.Data.SQLite 1.0.103 (just in case you want to know)

Answer (score 8):

I really think SQLite hates me - so instead of the query beeing

```
PRAGMA table_info('member');
```

I now used

```
SELECT * FROM member WHERE 1 = 2;
```

this of course will only return me the the table itsself without any content.
BUT - reader.GetName(i) is actually returning the real column names! Only took me 5hours trying to make 'PRAGMA table_info('table_name')' work to figure that out...

Comment: Upvoted! This helped me in Android actually. Doing `PRAGMA table-info(my_table_name)` returned 0. So I have applied your method and called `getColumnNames`. `getColumnIndex` is also the best if you wanted to check for field existance. Then the magic.

Answer (score 6):

The [PRAGMA table_info](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info) statement returns the data like a query, i.e., there is a fixed number of columns, and a number of rows with a value in each column. The data in each row corresponds to one column of the table you're asking about:

```
sqlite> pragma table_info(member);
cid      name          type     notnull  dflt_value  pk     
-------  ------------  -------  -------  ----------  -------
0        account_id    text     1                    0      
1        account_name  text     1                    0
```

Calling `GetName()` returns the column names. Call `GetString()` etc. to return the row values:

```
while (reader.Read()) {
    Console.WriteLine("field name: " + reader.GetString(1));
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure: I want the result to be something with 'account_id' and 'account_name' - as shown in the screenshot - I dont get those values in return..- http://puu.sh/rwfiZ/4166090e28.png

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on top of what [@CL.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39825471/1876355) said.

You can use `reader.GetOrdinal("ColumnName")` to get the correct column index

which is similar to `cursor.getColumnIndex("ColumnName")`:

```
var command = Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = $"PRAGMA table_info({entityType.Name});";

using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.HasRows && reader.Read())
    {
        do
        {
            int columnId = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("cid"));
            string name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("name"));
            string type = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("type"));
            bool notNull = reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("notnull"));
            object defaultValue = reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("dflt_value"));
            bool primaryKey = reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("pk"));

        } while (reader.Read());
    }
}
```