# Is it safe to depend on SQLite pragma statements

Tags: ios, sqlite, mobile

**Is it safe for my iOS application to depend on the functionality of specific pragma statements when interfacing with a SQLite database?**

According to the [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html):

> Specific pragma statements may be removed and others added in future releases of SQLite. There is no guarantee of backwards compatibility.

However, according to [this upvoted SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2520983/1529675):

> You can use a pragma to get the indexed columns:
>
> > PRAGMA index_info(index-name);
>
> And this one to get the column names for a table:
>
> > PRAGMA table_info(table-name);

My specific use case is that I would like my iOS application to check if a specific column exists before making a query via the FMDB SQLite wrapper. I am afraid that using `PRAGMA table_info(table-name)` may give unexpected results in a hypothetical future release of iOS that includes a newer version of SQLite in which the maintainers decided to drop support for this pragma statement.

Comment: Another option would be to try to prepare a statement that queries just that one column of a table. If the prepare statement fails, you know the column isn't there. Perhaps do this check once at app startup.

Comment: Thanks for the input. That is what I'm planning to do for now (i.e. `SELECT column-name FROM table-name LIMIT 1` and check for error).

Answer (score 1):

I'd be more inclined to use:

```
FMResultSet* results = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM tableName LIMIT 0"];
if([[results columnNameToIndexMap] containsObject:@"testColumn"])
```

Comment: Which I see now is pretty much what you decided to do while I was preparing it.

Comment: Yes very similar. Nice, didn't know `LIMIT 0` would work. Also didn't know about `-columnNameToIndexMap`. Thanks.