# DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Using SQLite 3.37.2. The following queries work:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MyTable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS...;
```

But a similar query on a column generates an error:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS MyField;
```

Remove `IF EXISTS` and the query works fine.

Does SQLite support `IF EXISTS` and `IF NOT EXISTS` for adding/dropping columns? This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520945/) appears to answer "no", though that was back in 2010. Perhaps something has changed in the latest version(s).

Comment: The [documentation of ALTER TABLE](https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) does not mention `IF EXISTS`.

Comment: True, which probably means that the answer is still "no". I note that the documentation on drop table (https://sqlite.org/lang_droptable.html) does mention `IF EXISTS`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This recent [SQLite forum question](https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/34a71b46b142c627) on the same subject is answered by the primary SQLite developer, Richard Hipp. Based on the Richard's answer, and the observation from @AnonCoward, the following is true:

As of v3.37.2 (January 2022), SQLite does NOT support either of the following:

```
ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS ...;
ALTER TABLE ... DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS ...;
```

#### UPDATE

There is currently a prototype implementation of this functionality in SQLite. The git check-in can [be viewed here](https://www.sqlite.org/src/timeline?c=460abf93ac6c47b0). Not slated for release in the upcoming v3.38.0 release, but sometime in the future.